# How do I re-render a chart in d3.js using an on click event (dashboard building)?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, d3.js

I’m developing an interactive school report card for a local nonprofit using Bootstrap, PHP, MySQL and d3.js.

I have no problem getting the d3 charts to render ([example](http://hendersonanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/results_before_ajax_v1.png)) once the user has selected a school (3 separate bar charts render onscreen when the user submits the school selection form).  I do this by executing queries, encoding them as JSON in PHP/MySQL, then using the PHP include function (on three separate occasions) to reference 3 separate JavaScript files that contain the d3 code that renders the charts.  The reference to the data that the d3 is pulling in to populate the graphs is nested inside of PHP tags inside each of these JavaScript files.  Again, no issues here, the charts render exactly where they’re supposed to and they look good.

The issue is that I’d like users to be able to be able to change the options on one of the charts and then have that chart re-render with the new data when a button in that form is clicked.

One of the charts that is initially rendered is of 4th grade math test score data from the state standardized test for the selected school.  There are other test subjects (English, Science and Social Studies) within the 4th grade that I’d like users to be able to view; additionally, the same 4 subjects are tested in grades 3 and grades 5 – 8.  These options for other tests and subjects appear in 2 select boxes that appear in a form located in a div that appears just above the test score graph’s div.

I use Ajax on change event handlers (raw JavaScript) to trigger a MySQL query with the selected options (subject and grade level; school is pulled from a hidden form element which contains the school id for the currently selected school) every time the user’s subject/grade level selection changes.  The JSON from the last query is then written into the value of another element that appears in the same form as the subject/grade level select boxes.  PHP/html for the form (I'm only using one on change handler in the code below):

```
echo "<form name='testselect' method=get>";
echo "<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>";
                echo "<select name='testtype' id='ttype' onChange='javascript:ajaxFunction();'>";       
                $dboxquery1 = "SELECT distinct subject FROM leapfile2012 WHERE site_code='$_POST[school]' ORDER BY subject;";
                $resultdbq1 = mysql_query($dboxquery1,$con) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());    
                while($dbqr1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultdbq1))
                    {       
                    echo '<option value="'. $dbqr1['subject'] . '">' . $testType[$dbqr1['subject']] . '</option>';
                    }
                echo "</select>";
            echo "</td>
            <td>";
        echo "<select name='testsub' id='tsub'>";
            echo "<option value='ELA' selected='selected'>English</option>";
        echo "</select>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type='hidden' name='hidden' id='hidename' value='" . $_POST['school'] . "'></input></td>";
            echo" <td>";
                echo '<input type="button" id="data-submit" value="Get" onClick="javascript:doofus();"></input>';
            echo "</td>
                   <td>
                     <input type='hidden' name='hidden2' id='hidename2' value=''></input>
                   </td>                                
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>";              
echo '</form>';
```

An on click event (user clicks ‘Get’ in the subject/grade level form) then triggers the d3 code that is supposed to repopulate the graph with the test data for the newly selected grade and subject.  The JSON for that new/updated graph is pulled from the value of that second hidden element.  This is where everything breaks down, I get an error running the following JavaScript/d3:

```
function doofus() {
    var birdmanbirdman = document.getElementById('hidename2').value;
    var whutitdo = birdmanbirdman.length;
    var quote_be_gone = birdmanbirdman.substring(0,whutitdo);
    //var i_hope_this_works = new Array(quote_be_gone);
    //alert(i_hope_this_works);
    //alert(typeof(i_hope_this_works));
    //alert(typeof(birdmanbirdman));

var margin = {top: 35, right: 105, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 370 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 289 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var data = new Array(quote_be_gone);

//var dontwant = ["site_name","site_code","subject","testsub"];

var formatAsPercentage = d3.format(".1%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#3366cc", "#dc3912", "#ff9900", "#109618", "#990099"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(1);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"))
    .tickSize(1);

var svg = d3.select("#area3").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key)
    { return key !== "year"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });

   x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("font-size", "1.0em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      /*.text("Population")*/;

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.year) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("stroke","black")
      .attr("stroke-width",0.5)
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  state.selectAll("text.one")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d,i) { return x.rangeBand()/2;})
      .attr("y", function(d) { /*if ((y(d.y0) - y(d.y1))>=0.05) */ return y(d.y1) + (y(d.y0) - y(d.y1))/2 + 6; })
      .text(function (d) { if ((y(d.y0) - y(d.y1))>=0.05) return formatAsPercentage(d.y1 - d.y0);})
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-weight", "normal")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-size", "0.9em");    

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width + 6)
      .attr("width", 12)
      .attr("height", 12)
      .attr("stroke","black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 100)
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("font-size", "9px")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "11px") 
    .style("font-weight", "normal")  
    /*.text(gtitle)*/;

}
```

When I inspect in Chrome, I get “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined” around this piece of code.

```
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });
```

In the debugging process, I’m able to alert out the JSON that’s supposed to populate the graph.  I’m then able to strip off opening and closing quotes using native JavaScript functions (the native data type is string), then successfully verify that the new data is indeed an object.  The d3 code in the on click script doesn't seem to be recognizing the new data/Object that I'm attempting to pass in.

I’m not sure what to do at this point.  I haven’t been able to find a parallel example online.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.  Forgive my wordiness, I wanted to make sure you all understood my issue in detail.  If this is an elementary error, please go easy on me.  I only started using JavaScript in March, PHP in April, and d3 six weeks ago.

Comment: Can you post the expanded call stack from the error? In Chrome, you can expand the error by clicking on the triangle to the left of the error string in console.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Is this what you're looking for?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined changegraph2.js:52
(anonymous function) changegraph2.js:52
doofus changegraph2.js:49
onclick repcard15.php:19

Comment: Look on line 52.  Is birdmanbirdman undefined when you reference length?

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

from Chrome console:
>birdmanbirdman.length
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error

Comment: Since birdmanbirdman is initialized from document.getElementById('hidename2').value you need to figure out why that element has an undefined value. Maybe break the lines apart so you can take a look at the element in the debugger and make sure its the one you're expecting.

Comment: @Scott Will do.  Also, I stumbled across some other d3 documentation  suggesting that I should be using d3's built in on click event listener instead of the one I built myself.  That would then trigger a function that overwrites the data that previously appeared in the chart and re-binds the rectangles to this data and creates new labels.  Will be working on that project again later this afternoon.  I'll report back on the progress.  Thanks again for your help.

[link to documentation](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch09.html#_updating_the_visuals)

Comment: @ScottCameron

I tried using the d3 event listener and plugging in var data = document.getElementById('hidename2').value directly.  This is the error I get.  Javascript apparently needs the data in another format: Uncaught TypeError: Object [{"year":"2010","site_name":"J. K. Haynes Elementary Charter School","Unsatisfactory":0.053,"Approaching Basic":0.263,"Basic":0.579,"Mastery":0.105,"Advanced":0},{"year":"2011",...,"Advanced":0}] has no method 'forEach'

How should I alter the JSON to enable JavaScript to parse it successfully?  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm losing the thread here. If you can put together a jsfiddle that shows the problem that would help. I'm not sure about your latest error.  Somehow the object you're calling forEach on isn't an Array.

Comment: @ScottCameron I was able to get the chart to re-render by using the JSON.parse method: 
var data=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("hidename2").value);

It needed that method to recognize it properly.  Not sure why I'm not able pass on the value of the 'hidename2' element to data by assigning it to another variable and then passing it to data by reference.  

Thanks again for your help.  I've never used jsfiddle before, so it would take some time before I could get something up.  Also, I'm not sure how I would integrate the server-side component of my example into it.